# Infinitely many "records" of uniform random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am doing the following exercise:

> Let $(U_n)_{n \geq1}$ be iid uniform random variables on $[0,1]$.
>   Define the event $E_n = U_n>\max \lbrace U_1, U_2, \dots, U_{n-1}
> > \rbrace$. I.e. the event that $U_n$ is bigger than all the preceding
>   realizations. Show that there will be inifnitely many of these events
>   almost surely.

So, intuitively this makes sense, since $P(U_n=1)=0$. I have tried to use Reverse Fatou Lemma to show that

$$
P(\limsup E_n)\geq \limsup P(E_n),
$$
but since $P(E_n) = 1-\max \lbrace U_1, U_2, \dots, U_{n-1} \rbrace$ and so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(E_n)=0$, I get
$$
P(\limsup E_n) \geq 0
$$
which doesn't help. Any hints are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $M_n = \max\{U_k, 1 \leq k \leq n\}$, then $P(M_n < 1 - \epsilon) = (1-\epsilon)^n$, so 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} P(M_n < 1- \epsilon) = \dfrac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon} < +\infty$$.

This means $E(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}1_{M_n < 1-\epsilon} )< +\infty$, i.e. almost surely only finite many $M_n$ are smaller than $1-\epsilon$. So we have $M_n \to 1$ almost surely.

Then remark that the event you defined happens only finite times means $M_m = U_n, \forall m \geq n$ for a certain $U_n$.

Since $M_n \to 1$ alomst surely, the event you defined happens only finite times implies $\exists n$ such that $U_n = 1$. You can easily get your conclusion from here.